# Java command is not executing in ksh by using Autosys job

Tags: java, unix, autosys

Autosys job is having command(running)`start.ksh`. Below is the code in `start.ksh`.

```
export classpath="jar files path";
nohup java javaclass>log.out &
```

If we run `start.ksh` manually java is creating a process but java is not creating prcoess if it runned by autosys job.
Please let me know what may be the issue?
There is no error in logs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you checked an Autosys job log ?

Comment: There has to be a difference between the command line environment variables are and what autosys uses with that process.  If.  You are not getting a file permission error and the current working directory is okay.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Current working directory is correct and there is no file permissions error. I have kept echo statement in last line in KSH. it is also executing but java process is not creating.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to troubleshoot this is to compare environment variables both when Autosys run the script and when it is run manually.

Create an Autosys job with the same user that runs the command "env" and run the same command manually and compare the outputs.